# Get row count on filter in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple html page showing a tests result.
User can filter the table rows on any text (mostly Test Name).

I want to show the a text for correct and incorrect answers.

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>sample html</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tbSearch").on("input", function() {
            searchTable($(this).val());
        });
    });

    function searchTable(inputVal) {
        var table = $("#myTable");
        table.find("tr").each(function(index, row) {
            var allCells = $(row).find("td");
            if (allCells.length > 0) {
                var found = false;
                allCells.each(function(index, td) {
                    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                    if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                        found = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (found == true) {
                    $(row).show();
                } else {
                    $(row).hide();
                }
            }
        });
        showCount();
    }

    function showCount(inputVal) {
        var table = $("#myTable");
        var totalRow = table.find("tbody tr:visible").length;
        var corr = table.find("tbody tr:visible").find("td:eq(2)").find(":contains('yes')").length;
        var incorr = table.find("tbody tr:visible").find("td:eq(2)").find(":contains('no')").length;
        $('#lblCount').text("Found " + totalRow.toString() + " Correct:" + corr.toString() + " Incorrect:" + incorr.toString());
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Search
    <input id="tbSearch" type="text" />
    <span id="lblCount"></span>
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test Name</th>
                <th>Equation</th>
                <th>Correct</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A001</td>
                <td>1+1=1</td>
                <td>no</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A001</td>
                <td>oslo is norway capital</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A001</td>
                <td>10+10=20</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A001</td>
                <td>1-1=0</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A002</td>
                <td>1+1=11</td>
                <td>no</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A002</td>
                <td>1+1=2</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A001</td>
                <td>11+1=11</td>
                <td>no</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A002</td>
                <td>1/1=1</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A003</td>
                <td>1-1=1</td>
                <td>no</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A003</td>
                <td>Polyester was invented by John Whinfield</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test-A003</td>
                <td>10+1=11</td>
                <td>yes</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I unable to get the count for yes and no rows.

```html
var corr = table.find("tbody tr:visible").find("td:eq(2)").find(":contains('yes')").length;
```

Please help in correcting the same.
Also if I want to show the same count on page load how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector you are using is wrong.

To get correct count:

```
var corr = $("table tr:visible td:nth-child(3):contains('yes')").length;
```

To get incorrect count:

```
var incorrect = $("table tr:visible td:nth-child(3):contains('no')").length;
```

Check Live [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/7ta9rj6a/1/)

`nth-child(3)` will select the last `td` in each `tr`

**On Page Load**

Use the same function inside `ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Use same code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!.
Curious to know what went wrong to
table.find("tbody tr:visible").find("td:eq(2)") gives proper list
.find(":contains('yes') gives an empty list.

Comment: last `find` will search for element inside `td`. There's none.